# script doesnt go to background

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm trying to write a simple script to send enable my leap motion controler.
enabling the device involves turning on a service, and launching the control panel.  The problem I am having, is that the service does not go to the background, and doesn't release my terminal.

The script is pretty simple, and resides in my $USER bin.

```
#!/bin/bash
LeapControlPanel &
sudo leapd &
```

[image]

Ignore the critical web socket stuff, I assure you the controller works, the only issue, is I want the service to return my prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script has gone to the background and has returned your prompt. The problem is that you aren't redirecting its output anywhere, so that still appears in your terminal. Sending a command to the background just means it will continue running and you can do other things in the parent shell. However, since the command is running, its output (both stdout and stderr) are still connected to your current terminal and that's why you still see them.

So, to send a command to the background *and* hide its output, you need:

1. Redirect stdout only so that any error messages are still printed to the terminal:

   ```
   ./leap > leap.log &
   ```
2. Redirect stderr only so that output but not errors still appears on the terminal:

   ```
   ./leap 2> leap.log &
   ```
3. Redirect both so that nothing is printed to the terminal:

   ```
   ./leap > leap.log 2>&1 &
   ```

   Or (if your shell supports it)

   ```
   ./leap &> leap.log &
   ```

In all examples, to discard the output instead of saving to a file, use `/dev/null` instead of `leap.log`.

Answer (score 1):

*It did* return you to the prompt -- it's on the second line of your screen capture. The error messages just messed up the display. Try typing a command, you will see it works. Or type Enter to get a new prompt.

Comment: nope, thats not the case